# Need to convert Oracle Nested table into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

I want to convert this nested type into PostgreSQL:

```
TYPE ATTACHMENTS_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you mean the datatype TEXT ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent.

You could use an array of text:

```
attachments_list text[];
```

Or perhaps you can create a temporary table.